# Concatonate a string to PHP variable

Tags: php, string, variables, concatenation

I have the code below, and I want to add tn_ before each of the image names. I have tried to use concatenation but I keep getting PHP errors.

```
data-retina="<?php echo site_url('uploads/'.$gal->image); ?>"/>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does this work? `data-retina="<?php echo site_url('uploads/tn_'.$gal->image); ?>"/>`

Comment: what value coming from $gal->image  ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
data-retina="<?php echo site_url('uploads/tn_'.$gal->image); ?>"/>
```